# Cometd how to make and subscribe channel dynamically?

Tags: java, servlets, comet, cometd, channel

I am trying to create a very simple cometD app.
Mainly i want to create channels dynamically.
First i tried localsession channels and after creating subscribed them via client side javascript.
It works perfect but not for dynamic channel creation.
Let i passed rom variable via javascript `ROOM: 'firstroom'`
this will create a channel like `"/members/firstroom".`

But on another call from another user like ROOM: 'anotherroom'
It creats another room but destroyed old room.

In simple words i want all dynamically created channels stored in memory.
Client session i tried:

```
ClientSessionChannel channel = _session.getLocalSession().getChannel('/members/'+room);
channel.publish(members);
```

Then i tried to create and subscribe on server like this:

```
ServerChannel channel = _bayeux.getChannel("/member"+room);
LocalSession localSession = _session.getLocalSession();

channel.subscribe(client);
ServerMessage.Mutable forward = _bayeux.newMessage();
forward.setData(_members);

channel.publish(localSession, forward);
```

But i thinking how server side subscribtion will change cliend side html code.
how

```
channel.publish(localSession, forward);
```

will replace

```
$.cometd.subscribe('/members', manage_members);
```

where manage_members goes in server side subscribtion.

Straight forward How to create and store channels dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand this question completely, but if the client knows the dynamic part of the channel, you can easily subscribe from JavaScript via:

```js
cometd.subscribe('/members/' + roomName, function(message) { ... });
```

See the [CometD JavaScript documentation about subscription](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#javascript_subscribe).

If the dynamic part is computed on server side, then your client - in order to receive messages, must subscribe to `/members/*` and filter out messages for unwanted rooms.
Alternatively, the server should send a message to the client telling it what is the exact channel to subscribe to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating channels dynamically from the server side you should look at the [`createIfAbsent` method of the `BayeuxServer` class](http://docs.cometd.org/apidocs/org/cometd/bayeux/server/BayeuxServer.html#createIfAbsent%28java.lang.String,%20org.cometd.bayeux.server.ConfigurableServerChannel.Initializer...%29). That allows you to specify the channel path and create (and initialise) the ServerChannel if it is absent.